# Combine multiple Marionette Behaviors to form complex Behavior

Tags: backbone.js, model, marionette, fetch, behavior

I've created 3 behaviors into one complex behavior.

The issue I have is that Marionette Behaviors communicate in one direction.. if I wanted use the behaviors hash and add a callback that refers to the complex behavior's function, the callback would have no reference to the view.

```
var ModelFetchable = Marionette.behavior.extend({
   onFetchNew: function (model) {
      var self = this;
      model.fetch({
         success: function (model, response) {
            self.options.successCallBack(model, response);

         }
      });
   }

var ComplexBehavior = Marionette.Behavior.extend({
behaviors: function () {
   return {
      ErrorDisplayable: {
         behaviorClass: ErrorDisplayable
      },
      ShelfAddRemovable: {
         behaviorClass: ShelfAddRemovable,
         template: this.options.template
      },
      ModelFetchable: {
         behaviorClass: ModelFetchable,
         successCallBack: this.displayResult,
      }
   };
},
onRenderModelSearch: function (row$) {
   this.view.triggerMethod('addShelf', row$);
   var model = new Model({
      entity: 'foo',
      row: row$,
      view: this.view
   });
   this.view.triggerMethod('fetchNew', model);
},
displayResult: function (model, response) {
   model.get('view').triggerMethod('removeShelf', model.get('row'));
}
```

When i trigger **onRenderModelSearch** and return my new model back to complex behavior's **displayResult**, it has no reference to the view and I can't trigger my ShelfAddRemovable behavior to **removeShelf**...

Are there any concerns I should be aware of when passing this or this.view into the model so that i can retain the ability to trigger **removeShelf**..

Any suggestions?

Thanks